# Don't have permission to set environmental variables via a script?

Tags: linux, permissions, environment-variables

I've written a script to add some environmental variable required to run a certain process. I use it in this way

```
>. ./env_change_script.zsh
```

using the leading dot to indicate I want the script run in this shell's environment.

However, when another user tried to use this, we got the error

```
/usr/local/bin/.: Permission denied.
```

The permissions for the script itself are fine, the user is able to run it without the leading dot (but of course that doesn't make the desired changes to their environment).

Is there some security setting that might be in place to prevent the user changing their environment via script in this way? If so, how can this setting be altered? Is there some other explanation?

Answer (score 1):

The user does not have dot `.` support in the shell. Ask the user to use `source` instead of `.` (dot).

Comment: Thanks, this doesn't seem to work as the user is using csh as their shell and the script is written in zsh. Using source seems to ignore the #!/bin/zsh at the start of the script and gives errors like "export: Command not found." (since csh wants to use setenv instead of export). Can I convince source to pay heed to the #!?

Comment: sourcing cannot change shell. if it is for zsh only, then the using shell has to be zsh or something compatible. they can run zsh first, then source the script, however.